# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, lampp

I am new to using the .htaccess file to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. I am using PHP codeigniter. I currently have this code in the file but when I load my website it gives a 503 error. I have been looking at so many resources online and trying different ways to accomplish this but none of them work for me.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?vista=$1

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type,http_authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

can someone render me some assistance? This is getting really frustrating :/

Comment: Does the error go if you remove the htaccess and test your site normally with `http` scheme?

Comment: The 503 error does not seem to relate to the directives you’ve posted? Are you suggesting (by the title) that the 503 only occurs when you try to implement the first rule (http to https redirect)? Otherwise your site works as intended?

Comment: Yes it only occurs when implementing the first rule otherwise everything else works